# Excel Vba 2007: use reference inside countifs

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(G$4:G$" & (i - 1) & _
                     ", Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(3, 25).Value ,F$4:F$" & (i - 1) & _
                     ",J4)"
```

I want to use this: `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(3, 25)`

so that I can make in loop to scan through column. as this reference cell must be fix. but I had error, it doesnt work.

Anyone help me please. Thanks o lot

Comment: err... it should be this:

ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(G$4:G$" & (i - 1) & ",  Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(3, 25).Value  ,F$4:F$" & (i - 1) & ",J4)"

But still dont work :(

Answer (score 0):

What stops you from using the actual address, `$Y$3`?

---

**EDIT**

Ah. You said you want this value fixed so I thought...

Then, you don't you just do the exactly same thing you're already doing in the rest parts of your formula?

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(G$4:G$" & (i - 1) & _ 
                     ", " & _
                     ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 25).Address(True, True, xlA1) & _
                     ", F$4:F$" & (i - 1) & _ 
                     ", J4)"
```

Comment: Because I use it in a loop, next loop, It will refer to next column so I want use cells(m,n) so that I can increase n in the loop

Comment: if i use $Y$3 then I dont know how to increase Y to Z

Answer (score 0):

You can use =CHAR() and =CODE() for the letters.  "A" can be represented by =CHAR(65), so any letter is 64 + (letter of the alphabet), so Y =CHAR(89).

If you want to go one column over from "Y", you can go CHAR(CODE("Y")+1) = "Z".

Also, CHAR(cells.column) will give you the column letter (assuming you are using the whole sheet).

Hope that makes sense. :)